Hot Water Line of Kitchen Sink Has Black Particle Bits
last year around January, I started to notice black particles coming out of our hot water in the kitchen.  The cold line does not have any funny black particles.   All other parts of our house also seems to be fine; no noticable black particles showing at all in bathrooms and laundry room.   These black particles also seem fragile;  when pressed, they seem to dissolve.  At first I thought it may be related to the water heater... howeverI completely replaced our gas water boiler with a gas tankless  water heater system in December last year..
Before I get a plumber involved, I was hoping to get some community opinion and solutions on the matter.   Attached are some photos of the particles.  I also included photo of the piping connection under sink in case it might afford some additional clues. You'll notice the there are 2 water lines coming out;  1 is for the faucet, and the other is for the dish washer.   I ran the dish washer as well, and did notice some black particles in the bowls left upright in there as well.  What are your thoughts on the cause and remedies?




Easiest cheapest source is a rubber washer going in a shut off valve.  That valve will not turn off the water when needed.

Thanks for the feedback, I'll open and check.

I have confidence the black bits are from the rubber washer in the shutoff valve.  It's degrading.
You will need to shut off water to the HW tank, or to the whole house.  Then remove the knob and stem of the valve and replace the washer. There are various sizes.
Go to your local hardware store and purchase a [Rubber washer assortment pack.
1.   Or take the washer with you and match it up.

Thanks a bunch, I will give this a try!

I can confirm this most likely is the cause of the problem.   I unscrewed the stem of the valve, and could see the black plastic decay.  I ended up replacing the whole stem with washers as it was just a few dollars.   The situation is semi fixed:

The black particle only appears when I open my valve all the way and open faucet to max volume.
When the water pressure is lowered, or the valve is only opened half way, the black particles are no longer visible.

I went with #2 to fix the problem for now.  Curious if any other root cause?
